# Generar número de longitud determinada en función del año

Tags: php, algoritmos

Necesito generar números consecutivos en función del año actual, es decir:

Mi primer número de este año es `20160001`.

Estos números tienen que estar en una base de datos, por ejemplo, tengo un número `20150820`, es decir en `2015` se han generado `820` números, pero cuando cambie de año, necesito que ese número, una vez generado en `2016` sea `20160001` y cada vez que se genere incremente en `1`.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para comprobar el cambio de año y reestablecer ese "contador" al cambiar de año?

Además si pongo esto:

```
$numero = 0001;
```

Al hacer `echo` de `$numero` el resultado es `1`, y no `0001`,
lo mismo pasa si hago esto:

```
$numero = "0001";
```

Para incrementarlo es fácil, saco el último guardado de la base de datos y le sumo `1`, pero para comprobar el cambio de año y generar ese número, no sé cómo hacerlo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que haría en tu lugar es extraer el año del último secuencial. Si dicho año coincide con el actual, basta con incrementar el secuencial (como bien has comentado). Sin embargo si los años no coinciden te toca reiniciar el secuencial.

Algo así:

```
$ultimoNumero = 20150672;
$anio = $ultimoNumero / 10000;
$anioActual = /* año actual */
if( $anio != $anioActual )
  $nuevoNumero = $anioActual * 10000 + 1;
else
  $nuevoNumero = $ultimoNumero + 1;
```

Comment: Gracias, así es como lo voy a hacer solamente que la variable $anio hay que hacerle (int)$anio para que sea igual al año actual

Answer (score 0):

Quizás puedas hacerlo todo en el mismo INSERT en MYSQL. Te paso la idea, no la he probado y le faltarán cosas, pero te pongo comentarios por si ves interesante la idea.

```
-- Insertamos en la tabla
INSERT INTO
    `table` (code, other_fields, ...)

VALUES
   (
    -- Vamos a obtener el índice actual + 1
    -- o 1 si no encontramos ninguno.
    -- NOTA: Habría que probar bien los casos base (cambios de año, ...)
    --       o hacer algún tipo de CASTING a entero
    SELECT 
        IF((code / 10000), (code / 10000) + 1, 1) 

    -- Lo sacamos de nuestra tabla
    FROM 
        table 

    -- Sólo queremos filtrar por el año actual. :year será "date('Y')"
    WHERE 
        code LIKE ':year%'

    -- Ordenamos por código 20160003, 20160002, 20160001, 20159999, ...
    ORDER BY 
        code DESC

    -- Y nos quedamos con el mayor (20160003 por ejemplo)
    LIMIT 1

),
'other_fields'
```